# Random Bluescreen of Death

Tags: visual-studio-code, blue-screen-of-death

I don't know if this is allowed here but can someone help me why am I getting this random blue screen? It say's **whea uncorrectable error** but I don't know which part of my PC is faulty. I noticed the BSOD appears when there is a heavy task like when I am coding in VSCode (running npm install, etc). I will attach here the minidump if someone can read it. If you need more information about my PC, let me know. Please I really need your help. I want to use this PC for programming. Thanks!

[Latest Minidump File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qyqGmTH8gCqncn0C6VVNXc4PjtGA_Lxj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You're asking at a wrong place, this site is for programming questions. Try https://superuser.com/

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens due to the high temperature in your pc, driver related issues or corrupted hardware. I recommend you try stopping overclocking for some time (if it is) and check if the problem persists. If not, then I think there could be a problem with your hardware itself. Try replacing the motherboard.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I don't overclock tho. I wanted to replace the parts of my PC, but unfortunately I don't have the budget yet to buy all parts so I wanted to figure out which one hardware causes the BSOD so I could replace it immediately.

Comment: Alright then, try replacing the motherboard